# HTML notes in freemind

Tags: html, freemind

I wonder if the following things can be done with the HTML notes pane of Freemind:

1. is it possible on the layout view to decrease the separation between lines?
2. the panel is horizontal, is it possible to setup a vertical view? (I have a big, horizontal-like monitor)

By the way, when I move the mouse pointer over a node, I can see the HTML note associated with it, but its view (as a yellow square) only lasts for some seconds. Can it be made permanent?

Comment: this is an interesting quesiton

Answer (score 1):

I've just looked through Freemind's config files: **auto.properties** and **user.properties** (usually in c:\documents and settings\.freemind) and can't see any relevant options.

**Maybe the best thing you can do is check if the latest version (0.9?) supports this and if not suggest these things to the developer?**